# Get max value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to create a new column in a Pandas Dataframe which includes the maximum value of another column up to this Point in time.
For example:

```
time  | value | max value   
 1        2        2  
 2        4        4  
 3        3        4  
 4        3        4 
 5        6        6
```

Does someone have an idea how to create a Code for the "max value" column?
Thanks

Comment: I think I have to clarify my question. The first column is the index of the Dataframe and it is a timestamp. The column "max value" should include the maximum value of the column "value" up to the specific date in the row.

Comment: j. DOE care to write a more roboust sample of data that ensures we meet your requirements?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html#pandas-dataframe-cummax):

```
df['max value'] = df['value'].cummax()
```

Output:

```
   time  value  max value
0     1      2          2
1     2      4          4
2     3      3          4
3     4      3          4
4     5      6          6
```

Answer (score 1):

What you said is the definition of `cummax`.

Just out of curiosity, you can also use [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html), which might come to be useful if you want to apply a custom function it.

```
df.value.expanding().max() # or .apply(custom_function)

0    2.0
1    4.0
2    4.0
3    4.0
4    6.0
```